# How to click on alert message using nightwatch.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing

I use nodejs + [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/) + chrome driver to run my e2e tests and got problem: i can't accept alert massage on page. In documentation for nightwatch i see information for [Selenium Protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidaccept_alert) to do this. But, when i try something like this:

```
request.post('/session/'+session+'/accept_alert', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

I get error:

```
[Error: Invalid URI "/session/9bb486d4-5e30-40bb-a236-b6921dd0f583/accept_alert"]
```

Can i accept alert from nightwatch? Or why i get this err? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [client.acceptAlert()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#acceptAlert) function